# Errors while Installing Cordova Ionic on Mac using npm

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my first time posting here and I was hoping to find some help...

So I have been trying to install Cordova and Ionic on my Mac using npm command... This is honestly the first time for me to try to install something through command line on Mac could you help me out understand what is going on?

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Shiro/.npm/_logs/2018-01-07T09_07_09_230Z-debug.log
```

I somewhat understood that it has to do with a permission error (Not completely sure tho) so I looked around and found this command to change ownership (I honestly have no idea what is that for...)

```
sudo chown -R
```

so after that I was supposed to enter a password but I couldn't figure out for what it should be cause the one for permissions I use did not work...

Comment: *Command Prompt (executable name cmd.exe) is the Microsoft supplied command line interpreter on OS/2, Windows CE, and all Windows operating systems (including Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10, Windows Server 2003, Server 2008, Server 2012, and Server 2016)*.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several recommended approaches for installing npm for the MacOS.
Using HomeBrew to Install npm

Many Macintosh developers use Homebrew, a valuable tool for managing apps and files.

**Before starting delete nodejs.**

1. To install Homebrew, [click here](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation.html).
2. After you've installed Homebrew, `run brew install node`
3. Homebrew will install Node.js and npm.

After that just run `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Comment: Well delete it & use Homebrew to install it again :/

Comment: I don't want to install homebrew, I've already solved the problem. I have them installed.

Comment: came back after two years to realize how foolish I was when I was doing this lol being much more experienced now makes me look at my old answer and feel ashamed, regardless thanks for the effort on this @melchia